# Pentaho CDE parameterized queries on Impala

Tags: sql, hadoop, pentaho, impala, pentaho-cde

I am trying to execute on Impala a parameterized query from Pentaho (version 5.0.6) CDE using the ${parameter_name} notation. I found out that if I remove the parameter and I hard-code the value in the SQL query, everything works fine, but if I put the parameter, everything stops working with the generic error message "Error processing component" (I am using the table component of CDE to show the values). In the pentahobaserver-stdout log file I found the following exception:

```
Jun 24, 2014 3:01:08 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException.getParentThrowable()Ljava/lang/Throwable;
```

Which seems to be a too generic error message (caused by this bug http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/CDA-79)

After some more investigation on the web, I think I bumped into [this](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-5076?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-186550) problem. For now I cannot avoid neither the use of parameters, nor the use of Pentaho nor the use of Impala, thus, I am stuck. Is there a workaround to this problem?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. The JDBC driver for Impala does not support parameters in PreparedStatements which is what is used in the Reporting libraries.

It's a hard one to solve. Probably the best way to workaround it is to use a Kettle transformation that dynamically builds the queries and issues them to Impala.

That way, parameter handling will be done at the Kettle level, but for Impala it will be a static query.

Comment: I tried by using a part of this example http://type-exit.org/adventures-with-open-source-bi/2011/02/dynamic-sql-queries-in-pdi-a-k-a-kettle/ ("Using Kettle Variables in the SQL Query" section) and importing the resulting .ktr file in CDE. I think that either I made some mistake or I missed some steps because the parameter has always its default value (configured with PDI). Could you please explain me what's the correct procedure in order to achieve this? Thank you

Comment: You need to use datasource parameters, like for any other CDA datasource. Those parameters will be mapped to Kettle variables when the transformation is executed.

Comment: At the end I found the solution. I created the kettle transformation by using a Table Input step. That's the only needed step. I put inside the parameterized query and I checked the box "replace variables in script?". In the transformation settings (opened by right clicking on an empty space) I configured the parameters and their default value. The resulting .ktr file was uploaded to Pentaho and then used in the Pentaho CDE dashboard, by creating a new "kettle over kettle TransFromFile" data source. The parameters' names and their default values were configured as in the .ktr file.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for posting your solution.